# How to implement Watir classes (e.g. PageContainer)?

Tags: ruby, class, watir

I'm writing a sample test with Watir where I navigate around a site with the IE class, issue queries, etc..
That works perfectly.

I want to continue by using [PageContainer](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Watir/PageContainer.html)'s methods on the last page I landed on.
For instance, using its HTML method on that page.

Now I'm new to Ruby and just started learning it for Watir.

I tried asking this question on OpenQA, but for some reason the Watir section is restricted to normal members.

Thanks for looking at my question.

**edit:** here is a simple example

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir"

test_site = "http://wiki.openqa.org/"

browser = Watir::IE.new

browser.goto(test_site)

# now if I want to get the HTML source of this page, I can't use the IE class 
# because it doesn't have a method which supports that

# the PageContainer class, does have a method that supports that
# I'll continue what I want to do in pseudo code

Store HTML source in text file

# I know how to write to a file, so that's not a problem;
# retrieving the HTML is the problem.
# more specifically, using another Watir class is the problem.

Close browser

# end
```

Comment: Someone out there must have an idea... anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the best place to get answers to your Watir questions is the [Watir-General](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-genera) email list.

For this question, it would be nice to see more code.  Is the application under test (AUT) opening a new window/tab that you were having trouble getting to and therefore wanted to try the PageContainer, or is it just navigating to a second page?

If it is the first one, you want to look at [#attach](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Watir/IE.html#M000224), if it is the second, then I would recommend reading the [quick start tutorial](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Quick+Start).

**Edit after code added above:**

What I think you missed is that [Watir::IE](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Watir/IE.html) includes the Watir::PageContainer [module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html).  So you can call `browser.html` to get the html displayed on the page to which you've navigated.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. It seems to me that `browser.html` is what you want.